# Website on nginx server requested from subdirectory

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

we have two nginx servers. The first server receives a request via `www.example.com/partner`. He sends the whole request to the second server which has php+fastCgi configured. Nginx access log from second server:

> "GET /partner/ HTTP/1.0" 200 2845

On the second server I have a vhost that looks like that:

```
server {
       listen my.ip:80;
       server_name www.example.com;
       root /var/www/example;

       if ($http_host != "www.example.com") {
                 rewrite ^ http://www.example.com$request_uri permanent;
       }

       index index.php index.html;


       location = /partner/favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
                expires max;
       }


        location @nocache {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
       }
       location = /partner/robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
       }

       location ^~ /partner/typo3temp/tx_ncstaticfilecache {
                expires 43200;
                charset utf-8;
       }

       location = /partner/clear.gif {
                empty_gif;
                expires max;
       }
       location ^~ /partner/typo3/gfx {
                expires max;
       }
       location ^~ /partner/typo3temp/compressor {
                expires max;
       }   

    location /partner {    


                if ($query_string ~ ".+") {
                        return 405;
                }
                # pass requests from logged-in users to PHP
                if ($http_cookie = 'nc_staticfilecache|be_typo_user' ) {
                        return 405;
                } # pass POST requests to PHP
                if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$ ) {
                        return 405;
                }
                if ($http_pragma = 'no-cache') {
                        return 405;
                }
                if ($http_cache_control = 'no-cache') {
                        return 405;
                }
                error_page 405 = @nocache;

                # serve requested content from the cache if available, otherwise pass the request to PHP
                try_files /typo3temp/tx_ncstaticfilecache/$host${request_uri}index.html @nocache;


       location ~* \.(sql|htaccess|htpasswd|tpl|html5|xhtml) {
                deny all;
       }

       location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
       }

       location ~* \.(cur|ico|gif|png|jpe?g|css|js|swf|woff)((\?\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)|(\?s=\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d))$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
       }
       location ~* \.(cur|ico|gif|png|jpe?g|css|js|swf|woff)(\?v\d\d?\.\d\d?\.\d\d?)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
       }
       location ~* ^(/typo3/sysext|/typo3conf/ext).*\.(cur|ico|gif|png|jpe?g|css|js|swf|woff) {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
       }



       location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
       }

       location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
       }
    }
}
```

The problem that the index.php is not interpreted, instead it is downloaded. Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: You forgot a semicolon at server_name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration is pretty similar to [this one](http://www.typofree.org/article/archive/2011/july/title/typo3-nginx-configuration-v2/), part you obviously missing is `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` in the root of the `server` block.

Another suggest is to try to use configuration exactly like from the link to make sure everything is working and it's not caused by your `location /` ifs. After that include `error_log ~/nginx_debug.log info;` in the `server` block and make your changes - you'll be able to understand which part of your configuration is broken.

Comment: the config is acutally from here http://www.howtoforge.com/running-typo3-4.6-on-nginx-lemp-on-debian-squeeze-ubuntu-11.10

Comment: I dont really get it why there is all that wordpress stuff in your config...

Comment: As I said I got typo3 working so far. But I want it to be accessable from my-site.com/partner. But I always get 404 error. With the config that I posted typo3 works great for a subdomain e.g. typo3.my-site.com...

Comment: no ^-^ do you mean I have to change all location / ?

Comment: hm the ^~ /partner thing does not seem to work either

Comment: Just realized:) Please try to add `location /partner` on the top of all locations and leave `listen my.ip:80;` outside only. And remove the `server_name www.example.com;` string.

Comment: What do you mean with " Please try to add location /partner on the top of all locations" Didn't I do exactly that above in my code?

Comment: "invalid number of arguments in location directive. As you can see there is /partner everywhere in the script above....this problem just drives me crazy ^^

Comment: I added you to my buddy list ;)

Comment: Please send me a mail to paskal-07@ya.ru.